# Three.js: FBX bones rotate correctly, while GLTF bones rotate bizarrely

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, gltf, fbx

I have a dynamic model working with an `FBX` file using `Three.js` `FBXLoader`, but out of convenience I wanted to use a `GLTF/GLB` file since it includes the textures in the same file. I loaded the `FBX` file in Blender 2.9 and exported it as `GLB` file. The `GLB` file renders correctly using the `GLTFLoader` but required a different rotation offset to put in the right orientation on setup.

Both the `FBX` and `GLB` file contain a `SkinnedMesh` with a similar bones array. I noticed that `matrixWorldNeedsUpdate` is false for the `GLB` model bones, but it's true by default with the `FBX`. There could be other differences, but I didn't explore other aspect of hierarchy more, like the matrix fields.

Anyway, when dynamically rotating the bones from the `GLB` file it almost seems like the pivot point is somewhere else. I'm updating the local rotation parameter as I should, so I don't know why it's manipulating the `Bone` in this fashion. It's rotating around the correct axis, so it just doesn't seem like it's using the correct local rotation.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    section1Bones[i].setRotationFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(0, 0, updatedSection1Vals[i], 'XYZ' ))
    section2Bones[i].setRotationFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(0, 0, updatedSection2Vals[i], 'XYZ' ))
    section3Bones[i].setRotationFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(0, 0, updatedSection3Vals[i], 'XYZ' ))
}
```

Comment: Maybe try using Blender 2.90?  There have been a lot of glTF fixes since 2.80.

Comment: My mistake, it was Blender 2.9 that I used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it's really the simplest thing. So unlike the `FBX`, the `GLB` includes separate components like the `scene` component which holds the 3D models. Since I had only one model I added the entire `scene` object into the `Three.js` scene and was rotating that along with the bones. This caused the issue, so I just included the `3DObject` contained in the scene components `children` of the loaded `GLB` file and the bone rotations were fixed.